# whenever I compile I get A jni error has occurred

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am completely new to java and have no idea what I'm doing. I wrote a very simple Hello World program and tried to compile it but when i tried to open the jar I got a Jni error has occurred message what should I do.

```
public class helloWorld {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Hello world");
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to open it through console? and how you made this jar file?

Comment: I made the Java file by building a artifact and I just try and open the file do I have to open it through console

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to run it through command line, just do this:**

`javac helloWorld.java` or `java -jar helloWorld.jar` (depends what you have)

**Or if you want to make `exe` file from `jar`, so you just need double click it to open, use:**

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

You can't just open the jar to run this code, at first you need a java runtime environment, and if you want to use command line to run this code,
you can use
java -c helloWorld.java
java helloWorld
to run it.